# Getting 400 bad request error in Wordpress Ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my single post page, I have created download button, If someone clicks on button then ajax will run and with that my php function will run, I am sending Ajax request in WordPress but it's returning `404 bad request` error.
**Here is the screenshot:**
[image]
**Here is the code:**

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.template_download_button', function(){

    var post_id = $(this).attr('data-postid');
    console.log(post_id);
    console.log(customJSAjax);
    console.log(customJSAjax.ajaxurl);

     $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url : customJSAjax.ajaxurl,
        data : {action: "template_downloads", post_id : post_id},
        success: function(response) {
             console.log(response);
        }
     });

});
```

**php:**

```
<?php

function inject_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'inject-custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), '20151215', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'inject-custom-js', 'customJSAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'inject_scripts' );

function template_downloads(){
    $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];

    var_dump($post_id);
    die();
}
add_action("wp_ajax_template_downloads", "template_downloads");
```

I am getting `post_id` from `<a>` tag's attribute of `data-postid`. I don't know why it's returning the `400` error. Please help me

Comment: Maybe you need to add add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_template_downloads','template_downloads' ); hook

Comment: solved buddy, thanks